# Online protected PDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf

I am building a site in which the administrator can upload reports or news in pdf format.

These pdf can be viewed online by regular users, but my client wants them not to be downloaded or copy-pasted easily, so that they can't be stolen or re-distributed.

I do understand that anyone with a little bit of computer knowledge can always manage to steal them anyways if they are being rendered in their computer, but what client wants is to prevent normal people from doing so without having to take a lot of screenshots.

Where do you recommend me to look in for achieving this goal? What is the easiest way? Is there any javascript way? Any recommended free plugin? Maybe with php?

Thank you all for your help and orientation.

Comment: Unfortunately if you make them visible, you make them downloadable.

Comment: impossible. by viewing them, the clients are already downloading them in some form. you cannot have "can't be downloaded" and "can be viewed" at the same time.

Comment: This is once more the always returning question to combine two incompatible things: you cannot at the same time publish information and keep it private. That simply does not make sense. And using terms like "not that easy" or "higher effort" only keeps things vague, it does not answer to the principal flaw of the approach. Use authentication if you feel like limiting direct access, but once the file is out it is out. Period.

Comment: But can't the pdf file be rendered in the browser, inside some html container, and do not provide any button to directly download, and prevent user from selecting and copying text from it? I have seen webs in which it is like that.

Comment: the browser still needs to know where to go to get the pdf, anyone viewing the source could get that link and just copy it,you could make it a small bit harder by disabling right clicks, you could possibly have php read the pdf and then output it as text to the browser scrambled in some way then have javascript on your page that makes sure it's your domain it is being shown on and  unscrambles it , just a couple quick thoughts

Comment: Hmmm, initially thought impossible. But, playing with your idea. You could try rendering the pdf in `canvas`. That would mean that your using javascript to decode an external file and display the raw image data, rather than exposing an actual .pdf file. Then you would need some way to secure the external file via `CORS` or `htaccess` so only your javascript could access it. Hmph, it may work.

Comment: @sweeds What you mean is, using javascript, fetch the pdf file, convert it into images, and place those inside a `canvas` ?

Comment: This is a complete waste of time, sorry.

Comment: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/ is a javascript library that can directly read a pdf and display it via canvas. That way you'd feed the javascript library an external url, and never expose the actual file itself. You would then have to limit who can view that url to only a specific IP or whitelist. This isn't a proven idea, but in theory it could work. But it's a lot of overhead -- i'd consider re-thinking how/why you're implementing it this way.

Comment: @sweeds that may work, I will give it a try. Thank you. Anyways, there is an authentication login to view the pdf's so I am not too much worried about security, I just want to please my client. Again, thanks

Comment: There are products such as my company Foxit's [WebPDF SDK[(https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/sdk/web-pdf-sdk/), Accusoft [Prizm](https://www.accusoft.com/products/prizm-content-connect-pcc/overview/), PDFTron [WebViewer](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/), etc. that are intended to allow you to show the user a document in a browser without making the entire document easily available to them. I would look into those.